# Re-reading structure in C

Tags: c, structure

I am trying to read structure from a file. Everything is correct until I close my app and open it again trying to read data.

1. write structure to the file (correct)
2. read structure from the file (correct)
3. close app
4. read structure from the file (incorrect)
5. List item

*Process terminated with status -1073741819 (0 minute(s), 6 second(s))*

My code:
logika.c

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include "logika.h"
int write_struc(char *PF, char *DF, char *TF, char *TL)
{
    struct MYSTR myStruct ={PF, DF, TF, TL};
    FILE* fb;
    if ((fb=fopen(PLIK_DAT, "a"))!=NULL)
    {
        fwrite(&myStruct, sizeof(struct MYSTR), 1, fb);
        fclose(fb);
        return 1;
    }
    else
    {
        return 0;
    }
}

void read_struc()
{
    FILE* fb;
    struct MYSTR myStruct;
    fb = fopen(PLIK_DAT, "r");
    while(1) {
        fread(&myStruct,sizeof(struct MYSTR),1,fb);
        if(feof(fb)!=0)
            break;
        printf("%s",myStruct.PF);
        printf("%10s" ,myStruct.DF);
        printf("%10s" ,myStruct.TF);
        printf("%10s\n", myStruct.TL);
    }
    fclose(fb);
}
```

logic.h

```
#ifndef LOGIKA_H_INCLUDED
#define LOGIKA_H_INCLUDED
#define PLIK_DAT "baza.dat"
int write_struc(char *PF, char *DF, char *TF, char *TL);
struct MYSTR{
    char *PF;
    char *DF;
    char *TF;
    char *TL;
};
#endif // LOGIKA_H_INCLUDED
```

I have tryied binary writting/reading and that does't helpes.

Comment: The general topic of this is called "Serialization". It can be very hard.

Comment: @HackSaw is serialization required if the struct members were data instead of pointers.

Comment: Are you familiar with the coding holes `fread(&myStruct,sizeof(struct MYSTR),1,fb);
        if(feof(fb)!=0)
            break;` has and not with `if (fread(&myStruct,sizeof(struct MYSTR),1,fb) != 1) break;`?

Comment: Serialization is about storing the data including the data about the data, such as relationships. Pointers are an implementation detail which is very likely to change due to what's running on the system at the time you are running your program. You're reasonably unlikely to land in the same memory space, so the pointers will change, but that's okay, because we don't need to care about them, we need to know the relationships.

Comment: OT:  When calling `fopen()`, always check the returned value to assure the operation was successful

Comment: OT: regarding: `    while(1) 
    {
        fread(&myStruct,sizeof(struct MYSTR),1,fb);
        
        if(feof(fb)!=0)
            break;`  This mess is not necessary.  Rather use: `    while(   fread( &myStruct, sizeof( struct MYSTR), 1, fb ) == 1 )`

Comment: True indeed:  ```while (true) { if (something) break; .... }``` is a weirdly-frequent anti-pattern.

Answer (score 7):

Your structure contains 4 addresses.  Those addresses are meaningless outside of your program.  If you're expecting the string data (what's at the addresses contained in the struct) to get written out, you'll have to do that yourself, and design a file format that will allow you to reconstruct the data on input.

Within one execution of your program, you get "lucky" because the data at those addresses has not changed, so it looks like it worked.  But it did nothing useful.

Answer (score 0):

the following proposed code:

1. cleanly compiles
2. properly checks for errors
3. properly defines the struct for reading/writing to a disk file
4. modified where the function prototypes are defined

Note: I incorporated the header file into the main code, which you probably do not want to do.

And now, the proposed code:

```
#ifndef LOGIKA_H_INCLUDED
#define LOGIKA_H_INCLUDED

// prototypes
int write_struc(char *PF, char *DF, char *TF, char *TL);
void read_struc( void );

#define MAX_STRING_LEN 1024

struct MYSTR
{
    char PF[ MAX_STRING_LEN ];
    char DF[ MAX_STRING_LEN ];
    char TF[ MAX_STRING_LEN ];
    char TL[ MAX_STRING_LEN ];
};
#endif // LOGIKA_H_INCLUDED


#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
//#include "logika.h"

#define MAX_BUF_LEN 256
#define PLIK_DAT "baza.dat"

int write_struc(char *PF, char *DF, char *TF, char *TL)
{
    struct MYSTR myStruct;
    strncpy( myStruct.PF, PF, MAX_STRING_LEN );
    strncpy( myStruct.DF, DF, MAX_STRING_LEN );
    strncpy( myStruct.TF, TF, MAX_STRING_LEN );
    strncpy( myStruct.TL, TL, MAX_STRING_LEN );

    FILE* fb;
    if ( !(fb=fopen(PLIK_DAT, "a")))
    {
        char buffer[ MAX_BUF_LEN ];
        sprintf( buffer, "fopen to append to %s failed", PLIK_DAT );
        perror( buffer );
        return 0;
    }

    // implied else, fopen successful

    if(  fwrite(&myStruct, sizeof(struct MYSTR), 1, fb) != 1)
    {
        perror( "fwrite failed" );
        return 0;
    }

    // implied else, fwrite successful

    fclose(fb);
    return 1;
}


void read_struc()
{
    struct MYSTR myStruct;
    FILE* fb;
    if( !(fb = fopen(PLIK_DAT, "r") ) )
    {
        char buffer[ MAX_BUF_LEN ];
        sprintf( buffer, "fopen to read %s failed", PLIK_DAT );
        perror( buffer );
        exit( EXIT_FAILURE );  // if program can recover, then use `return;`  rather than `exit()`
    }

    // implied else, fopen successful

    while( fread(&myStruct,sizeof(struct MYSTR),1,fb) == 1)
    {
        printf("\n%s", myStruct.PF);
        printf("%s",   myStruct.DF);
        printf("%s",   myStruct.TF);
        printf("%s\n", myStruct.TL);
    }
    fclose(fb);
}
```